# Writing a python method that refers to both the instance and the class

Tags: python, oop, class-method

Let's say we have a Pet class in Python:

```
class Pet(object):
    num_pets = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Pet.num_pets += 1

    def speak(self):
        print("My name's %s and the number of pets is %d" % (self.name, self.num_pets))
```

I want the **init** method to create an instance, but also update an attribute on the class. Is there a more elegant way to do this than the code above? I tried passing in `self` and `cls` to the init method, and then referring to cls instead of Pet where num_pets is incremented, but that didn't work.

Comment: I see the above code to be elegant enough. Unless `num_pets` is an attribute that's managed per-class. I don't see any obvious reason why to consider the need of using a class method here.

Answer (score 13):

You could use a `classmethod` to increment the number of pets:

```
class Pet(object):
    num_pets = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.incr_num_pets()

    @classmethod
    def incr_num_pets(cls):
        cls.num_pets += 1
```

Alternatively, you could increment `num_pets` on `type(self)`:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    type(self).num_pets += 1
```

though I find this second method to be slightly less elegant even if it is less typing.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you could use [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) together with `__init__`:

```
class Pet(object):
    num_pets = 0

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.num_pets += 1
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access own class using `self.__class__`, it means that your `__init__` can looks like:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.__class__.num_pets += 1
```